# Cannot get CSS transition property with jquery in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, css-transitions

I'm attempting to read out the transition property of an element, however, I only get an empty string. The element has a transition applied to it, as I can see it.

I'm using jQuery's `.css()` to achieve this. For example, the following code

```
// in css
#transitionElement {
    transition: height 0.5s ease;
}

// and in JS
$('#transitionElement').height('59px');
console.log($('#transitionElement').css('transition'));
console.log($('#transitionElement').css('-moz-transition'));
```

triggers the transition, I can see it, but logs 2x `(empty string)`.

In Chromium the `.css('transition')` works just fine.

Any ideas how to make this work in Firefox?

**Edit**:

Seems you can't read out the whole transition as string (as pointed out by jimmyweb) in firefox. Came op with a cssHook to help myself out. Don't know about other browsers maybe i can test this sometime.

```
if($.browser.mozilla) {
    $.cssHooks[ "transition" ] = {
        get: function( elem, computed, extra ) {
            return $.css(elem, 'transition-duration')
                 + ' ' + $.css(elem, 'transition-property')
                 + ' ' + $.css(elem, 'transition-timing-function');
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this is weird that `transition` property is empty, but other properties that `transition` consists of are accessible, so you can concatenate whole `transition` value. You can get CSS properties values by using `getComputedStyle` method, as well. Your console should print out every property except the first one and delay value (if you don't provide it), which is empty string:

```
var element = document.getElementById('transitionElement'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    console.log(style.getPropertyValue('transition'));
    console.log(style.getPropertyValue('transition-delay'));
    console.log(style.getPropertyValue('transition-duration'));
    console.log(style.getPropertyValue('transition-property'));
    console.log(style.getPropertyValue('transition-timing-function'));
```

Always remember also to provide vendor prefixes for older versions:

```
#transitionElement {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: thanks this was working. indeed weird that firefox doesn't do this. Posted a little code snippet to "fix" it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not just limited to Firefox<=23, but also occurs on Safari<7 iOS<7 and IE<=11, so I created a more generic solution that also supports transition delay and multiple by commas separated declarations like:

```
transition: transform 1500ms cubic-bezier(0,0.6,1) 1s, left 500ms;
```

Here are my jQuery plugin and helper function:

```
/**
 * PROBLEM: FF<=23, IE<=11 and Safari<7 return empty strings on 
 *   $elm.css('-prefix-transition').
 * SOLUTION: Retrieve transition properties separately and compose full version.
 *
 * See answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21139827/328272.
 */
jQuery.fn.getTransitionStyle = function(transitionPrefixed) {
  var $elm = this;

  if ($elm.css(transitionPrefixed)) return $elm.css(transitionPrefixed);

  // Transition properties to iterate through.
  var properties = 'property duration timing-function delay'.split(' '),
    result = [], valueArray, i, j;

  // Iterate through transition properties.
  for (i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
    // Get property value and split by comma.
    valueArray = $.css($elm[0], transitionPrefixed + '-' + properties[i]).splitCssStyleByComma();

    // Iterate through 
    for (j = 0; j < valueArray.length; j++) {
      // Add value to return array.
      result[j] = (result[j] ? result[j] + ' ' : '') + valueArray[j];
    }
  }
alert(result.join(', '));
  return result.join(', ');
};

/**
 * Split CSS style by commas while ignoring commas between parenthesis.
 * Example:
 * Input string: "transform 1500ms cubic-bezier(0,0.6,1), left 500ms"
 * Output array: ["transform 1500ms cubic-bezier(0,0.6,1)", "left 500ms"]
 */
(function() {
  var regExpString = '\\s*(' + '([^,(]+(\\(.+?\\))?)+' + ')[\\s,]*',
    regExpMain = new RegExp(regExpString),
    regExpValidate = new RegExp('^(' + regExpString + ')+$'),
    string, result;

  String.prototype.splitCssStyleByComma = function() {
    string = this, result = [];

    // DEBUG: Validate value to prevent an infinite loop.
    if (!string.match(regExpValidate)) {
      console.log('ERROR: Cannot split CSS style by comma: "' + string + '"');
      return false;
    }

    // As long as there is a string left, chop off the parts we desire.
    while (string.match(regExpMain)) {
      // Add value to return array.
      result.push(RegExp.$1);

      // Remove value from string.
      string = string.replace(regExpMain, '');
    }

    return result;
  };
})();
```

Use the plugin in the following way. I use `Modernizr.prefixed()` to find the optionally prefixed version of the transition style name, but any other method will ofcourse do:

```
var transitionNamePrefixed = Modernizr.prefixed('transition');
var transitionStyle = $('.element').getTransitionStyle(transitionNamePrefixed);
```